# Prove that for $X = \mathbb{N}$ and $V_n=\{n,n+1,n+2,n+3,...\}$, $\tau = {\emptyset} \cup \{V_n:n\geq 1\}$ is a topology in X.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have such a task but I can't solve it. I don't know where to start. Any hint would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I do not think that $\tau$ is a topology because it does not contain $X=\mathbb{N}$ unless you change the definition of $\tau = \emptyset \cup \{V_n : n \ge 0\}$ or the definition of $X = \mathbb{N} \backslash \{0\}$. In these cases it is enough to check the definition of a topology.

Comment: What have you tried ? What properties do you need to show to prove that this is a topology ?

Comment: I want to prove it by checking the 3 axioms.

Comment: I can't prove the second axiom

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $\mathbb N$ refers to the set of positive integers and
$$
\tau = \{\varnothing\} \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{V_n\},
$$
it is immediate that $\mathbb N=V_1\in\tau$. If $V_i,V_j\in\tau$ with $i<j$, then $V_i\cap V_j=V_j\in\tau$, so $\tau$ is closed under finite intersections (and the intersection of any set with $\varnothing$ is $\varnothing$ which is again in $\tau$).

Now suppose $\{V_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ is a nonempty family of sets in $\tau$. We may assume that no $V_\alpha=\varnothing$ since union of any set with the empty set yields the original set. Since each $\alpha\in\mathbb N$, by the well-ordering principle $I$ has a least element $m$. As $i<j$ implies $V_i\subset V_j$, it follows that 
$$
\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}V_\alpha = V_m\in\tau,
$$
and hence that $\tau$ is a topology.